# How to fix Variable 'installStateUpdatedListener' might not have been initialized

Tags: java, android

> Variable 'installStateUpdatedListener' might not have been initialized

How to solve this problem

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjATB.png)

.InstallStateUpdatedListener not working
`

```
InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener;


        InstallStateUpdatedListener finalInstallStateUpdatedListener = installStateUpdatedListener;
        installStateUpdatedListener = state -> {
            if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                launchSnackBar();
            } else if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.INSTALLED){
                if (appUpdateManager != null){
                    appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(finalInstallStateUpdatedListener);
                }
            } `
```

How to fix Variable 'installStateUpdatedListener' might not have been initialized

Comment: In the code in your question, variable `installStateUpdatedListener` is not assigned a value, so when you assign it to another variable - `finalInstallStateUpdatedListener` - you get the error. Looks like you need to assign a value to variable `installStateUpdatedListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you defined `installStateUpdatedListener`, you have not supplied it with an initial value.

That is why you are getting the error you are seeing.

You need to supply `installStateUpdatedListener` with an initial value.

You could either set with null or with a value when you are declaring it.

I.E.

```
InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener = null;
```

If you are giving it a null value, make sure you check that it isn't null when you are using this variable.

Comment: old version mobile install  new version playstore upload not show my android update toast message

Comment: @SyedGhouser - Your comment is unclear, but if you have a different question, please post a new one.